# path.getTotalLength() seems to returning wrong value?

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to get the total length of a path, which is essentially a straight line:
https://jsfiddle.net/36u7Lztv/9/

the result is about 312, which is about the same as my manual calculation.

However, if I add more intermediate points ( visually should still be a straight line):
https://jsfiddle.net/36u7Lztv/8/

the result is now 347... any idea why is that?
Below is the code I borrow from another post for testing.

Thanks!!

HTML:

```
<svg  width="1023.5735" height="339.87985" viewBox="0 0 1023.5737 339.87985" >            
        <path id='lens_right' class='lens'
            d="M 103.25 46.88 C 103.25 46.88 188.38 347.46 188.38 347.46" stroke="blue" fill="transparent" />"
</svg>

<p id="log">
  path length:
</p>
```

CSS:

```
svg {
  width: 50%;
}

svg path {
  fill: #000000;
  fill-opacity: 1;
  stroke: #ffffff;
  stroke-width: 10;
  transition: all 3s linear;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var path1 = document.getElementById('lens_right');
var path1Len = path1.getTotalLength();

var strokeLen = path1Len; // easier troubleshooting

document.getElementById('log').innerHTML = 'path length: ' + path1Len;

path1.style.strokeDasharray = strokeLen;
path1.style.strokeDashoffset = -strokeLen;

// add/remove border on hover
document.body.onmouseover = function() {
    path1.style.strokeDashoffset = '0';
}

document.body.onmouseout = function() {
    path1.style.strokeDashoffset = -strokeLen;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your second example is not a straight line. It consists of two seperate paths. The second one is

```
M 183.64,330.72 C 197.83,380.81 193.1,364.13 188.38,347.46
```

The cubic bezier intermediate points are beyond the end point, and the path loops to (approx.) `193.1,364.13` before it comes back to `188.38,347.46`.

Comment: thanks!! the intermediate curving control points do look suspicious, will see how I get them...